# How can you hide something from registered users but display it to anonymous users?

Tags: plone

This is for Plone 4. It is quite a general problem. I have a form (ploneformgen) that I want anonymous users to see and fill in, but I want to hide it from registered users (i.e., users who have logged in). Similarly, I have a "log in" link in the navigation menu. Obviously, anonymous users should see that, but logged-in users shouldn't have to see it. I've tried many options which I won't detail here (workflows, scripts that change local permission settings, etc.) since none of them have worked. There must be a standard way of doing this, but I can't work out what it is.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but it might work: [`Products.AutoRole`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.AutoRole/2.1.1) can assign groups and roles to visitors based on their IP, without creating user accounts for them. It also has a switch to only give automatic roles/groups to anonymous users. A rule `255.255.255.255/0` should match all IPs, so all anonymous users get a group, and you can make the form private and visible to that group.

(Note that AutoRole is not IPv6-ready, though, and has caveats regarding user inheritance, particularly: it will de facto disable the admin account, so you should *not* activate it in your Plone instance, but in the Zope server `acl_users`, if at all possible.)

Comment: This looks promising, but I think I'm missing something. I installed AutoRole, activated it (through Plone), went to "Properties" tab on "Plone/acl_users/auto_role", and in the "IP filter and roles" field I entered "255.255.255.255/0:GroupThatCanViewForm", where all members of the group "GroupThatCanViewForm" can view the particular form I want anon users to be able to see. However, it doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something? I see that there is an auto_group plugin as well, is that relevant?

Comment: @adam: you need Authentication, Extraction, Groups in the Activate tab; the default install settings are Authentication, Extraction, Roles, maybe it's that.

Answer (score 0):

Another untested idea.

There's a not a very know product and I never used it in a production environment (but in my tests it works perfectly): collective.subtractiveworkflow (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.subtractiveworkflow) and the use of workflow chain.

In practice you can design a second workflow where `View` permission will be subtracted from `Member` roles.

To be honest I'm not 100% sure of how this can work with `Anonymous`, just because normally you can't define permission for Anon users but not given to other roles. This can be the same in that situation.